# How to fix " Class" is not a valid entity or mapped super class. ? Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, entities, symfony-2.8

Actually I've generated my entity Ticket from console with the next command:
**php app/console doctrine:generate:entity**
And it has generated the entity correctly with the respective getters and setters.

```
namespace RelacionesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Ticket
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ticket")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="RelacionesBundle\Repository\TicketRepository")
 */
class Ticket
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return Ticket
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Ticket
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I edit the entity adding another property:

```
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="explanation", type="string", length=150)
     */
    private $explanation;
```

When I enter the following command:
**php app/console doctrine:generate:entities RelacionesBundle/Entity/Ticket**

I get this error:
 Class "RelacionesBundle\Entity\Ticket" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.

Any Advice? or what is wrong?

Comment: I've already added the annotation @ORM/Entity but It shows the same error

Comment: There's also other possibilities at that question. Check them please. Be sure if your configuration is correct. Ofcourse don't forget to set psr-4 or psr-0 config in composer.json.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same exception by deleting a conflicting autogenerated orm.php file in the bundle's Resources/config/doctrine folder; according to the documentation: "A bundle can accept only one metadata definition format. For example, it's not possible to mix YAML metadata definitions with annotated PHP entity class definitions."